# ActiveMq transaction on @JmsListener

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-jms

I try to make a Jms consumer with activeMq broker witch have an "transactional" acknowledge. I want to use spring boot application.

I read that I need JTA transaction but I don't know how I can start one.

My main class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJms
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

My consumer :

```
@Component
public class ReceiveMessage {
    @JmsListener(destination = "${jms.queue.destination}")
    public void receiveMessage(final String msg) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Received:" + msg);
    }
}
```

My pom.xml dependency :

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-activemq</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

What I have to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

update your consumer :

```
@Component
public class ReceiveMessage {
    @JmsListener(destination = "${jms.queue.destination}", containerFactory = "jmsListenerContainerFactory")
    public void receiveMessage(final String msg) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Received:" + msg);
    }
}
```

add these beans :

```
@Bean
public JmsListenerContainerFactory<?> jmsListenerContainerFactory(
        ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
        DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer) {
    DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
    configurer.configure(factory, connectionFactory);
    factory.setTransactionManager(transactionManager());
    return factory;
}

@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
    JmsTransactionManager transactionManager = new JmsTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setConnectionFactory(jmsConnectionFactory());
    return transactionManager;
}

@Bean
public QueueConnectionFactory jmsConnectionFactory() {
    ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("tcp://localhost:5672");
    return connectionFactory;
}
```

Comment: It works but it's bypass the spring boot autoconfiguration

Comment: yep the same like uses a specific MessageConverter https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-messaging.html#boot-features-using-jms-receiving

Comment: thx for your input. works great on an isolated project I created. On existing projects though I run into a "org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: No EntityManager with actual transaction available for current thread" on the transactionManager() method. Has somebody else ran into this? I can open a new thread if needed.