# ActiveMQ transactional acknowledge - on a topic consumer -

Tags: spring-boot, transactions, activemq-classic

(On a springboot project implementing pubsub via activeMq), I'd like to have a transactional acknowledge on the consumer's "listener", so that if any exception arises, the message broker (in this case activeMq) just keeps retrying the delivery - according to some retrial policy - (or more likely the consumer keeps pulling).

Exactly this has been asked & successfully answered here: [ActiveMq transaction on @JmsListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43409193/activemq-transaction-on-jmslistener)

Although I tested that and it works correctly, it did only work for queues; for topic consumers no "retrial mechanism" is working despite being configured basically identically.

Does anybody know if (regarding transactional consumers), there is some fundamental difference between queues and topics? and/or if there is some common problem/pitfall when using transactional consumers with topics?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In case somebody faces this problem in the future, the solution to the problem was making the subscriber "durable". As to why does this solve the problem I'm not 100% sure; but I'd speculate that a durable subscriber (since it has the capability to "store messages for later delivery" even when a consumer/subscriber is offline), it has the "setup" necessary for retrial in case of a "failed acknowledged delivery".

In case of virtual topics, to achieve this "transactional" behaviour; then durable topics need to be set to false (since virtual topics are physical queues from the consumer perspective), and we also need to set pubSubDomain false;